# "double salting" a password with python

Tags: python, php, sha1

I want to make a "double salted" password in python it should give the same result as the php code below.

The php code: `sha1($salt . sha1($salt . sha1($password)));`

Hopefully someone can help me with my issue.

Comment: You can salt till the cows come home, sha1 will remain unsafe to hash and store passwords with. Use `password_hash()` instead and have them update their passwords.

Comment: @Alfred der Große how much users do you have?

Comment: about 5000 users

Comment: I do not plan on using sha1 as the primary hasher and django should update their passwords as soon they log in.

Comment: And what's the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply [`functools.reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) here:

```
from hashlib import sha1
from functools import reduce

result = reduce(lambda a, b: b + sha1(a.encode()).hexdigest(), (password, salt, salt, ''))
```

You can also chain function calls *(which will be ~30% more effective, but not as compact)*:

```
from hashlib import sha1

result = sha1((salt + sha1((salt + sha1(password.encode()).hexdigest()).encode()).hexdigest()).encode()).hexdigest()
```